# Use mysql password() function with Laravel authentification

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I am migrating an old php-html website to vuejs/laravel.

There are already thousands of users so I guess I can't change the password cypting. For now, only mysql password() method is used to crypt it, and then we check that password(password)==password(authpassword).
But is it possible to add this password() in my laravel authentification? I already removed Hash.

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)
        ->where('pwd', $request->password)
        ->first();
    if($user) {
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
}
```

registration

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'nom' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'pwd' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'login' => $data['email'],
        'pwd' => ($data['password']),
        'type' => 'P'
    ]);
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the password stored in plain text? Then you could easily switch to the method laravel is using.

Comment: it is store in plain text yes, through this https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/how-mysql-protects-your-password.html. Do you mean Hash method?

Comment: `password()` has been removed from newer mysql versions and it seems it does not use a unique salt per hash, so you should try to move away from it as soon as possible. For example by adding a new, modern hash like bcrypt, hash it for users that are successfully logging in for a period of time and at the end of that period send a password reset mail to the users that have not logged in yet. Then you can remove the old one completely.

Comment: I don't see any added security from `password(password) = password(authpassword)` (beside from maybe case sensitivity, based on your collation). If you have the plain text password of every user you can create the hash with `Hash::make($plainPassword)` and then use the default laravel bahavior.

Comment: @RolandStarke I hope that is just pseudo-code to illustrate how the passwords are matched and not how it actually done :-)

Comment: please notice the warning in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) **PASSWORD() is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications**

Comment: i strongly advice you to read [Safe Password Hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords) and stop thinking off using `PASSWORD()`  for your users in your application.. Like @RolandStarke already suggest (more or less)  Laraval most likely has wrapper classes/functions for it.

Comment: Thanks. Well, this has been done many years ago and I don't see any inconvenient in changing it... I have now absolutely no idea how to do so though but I will think about it and suggest sending an email with password reset to all users.